# class inside another class in python

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

I dont know how to get output "two"
Please help with that

```
class Main:
    class main2():
        def two(self):
            print 'two'
    def one(self):
        pass
        #self.main2.two()




boo = Main()
boo.one()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as `two` is a member function (has a `self` as first argument) instances of the `Main` class probably need an instance of the inner class as member:

```
class Main:
    class main2():
        def two(self):
            print('two')
    def one(self):
        self.m2.two()
    def __init__(self):
        # here the instance gets an instance of the class Main.main2
        # as member
        self.m2 = Main.main2()


boo = Main()
boo.one()
# boo.m2.two()
```

or you directly create an instance of the inner class:

```
m2 = Main.main2()
m2.two()
```

Comment: You don't need boo; just Main. will do

Comment: sure, added that. was not sure what your question really was.

Comment: function one from class Main must start function two from class main2.
how to make it work ?

Comment: @assffggew: made a minor changement: `one` now calls `two`.

Answer (score -1):

```
Main.main2().two()
```

Main. - for main2 is a class defined within Main and therefor is an attribute of that class

main2() - to instantiate the subclass

two() to execute the method

Answer (score -1):

You just missed one statement, you are not calling the method yet.

```
outer = Main()
inner = outer.main2()
# You can now call the method 
inner.two()
```

Comment: There's no need to instantiate the outer class

Comment: And there no need to use a inner class to print "two". The OP ask how he should use it, the class will probably be used instanciated later..

Answer (score -1):

The following line print the output:

```
boo.main2().two()
```